# Pandas: Resample grouped dataframe column, get discrete feature that corresponds to max value

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, max, resampling

This is similar to a previous question I've asked but sufficiently different as the solution doesn't work when the data is grouped:

Given some data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime

data = {'group':['a', 'a', 'a','b','a', 'b'], 
        'value': [1,2,3,4,3,5], 'names': ['joe', 'bob', 'greg','joe', 'bob', 'greg'],
        'dates': ['2015-01-01', '2015-01-02', '2015-01-03', '2015-01-03', '2015-01-04', '2015-01-04']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=["group", "value", "names"], 
                  index=pd.to_datetime(data['dates']))
```

Gives:

```
           group value names
2015-01-01     a     1   joe
2015-01-02     a     2   bob
2015-01-03     a     3  greg
2015-01-03     b     4   joe
2015-01-04     a     3   bob
2015-01-04     b     5  greg
```

I wish to get:

```
            group value names
2015-01-01      a     2   bob
2015-01-03      a     3   bob
2015-01-03      b     5  greg
```

So the data is grouped, resampled by 2 days ('2D'), then the name corresponding to the maximum 'value' is collected 
I have tried the following which gives an error:

```
(df.groupby('group').resample('2D')[['value']].idxmax()
   .assign(names=lambda x: df.loc[x.value]['names'].values,
           value=lambda x: df.loc[x.value]['value'].values)
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `apply` after grouping to sort the value, names columns by value and then take the first row.

```
g = df.groupby(['group', pd.Grouper(freq='2D')])[['value', 'names']]
g.apply(lambda x: x.sort_values(['value', 'names'], ascending=[False, True]).iloc[0])\
 .reset_index('group')

           group  value names
2015-01-01     a      2   bob
2015-01-03     a      3   bob
2015-01-03     b      5  greg
```

This is the same as using resample

```
g = df.groupby(['group'])[['value', 'names']]
g.resample('2D').apply(lambda x: x.sort_values(['value', 'names'], ascending=[False, True]).iloc[0])\
 .reset_index('group')
```

Comment: Super. I know that we're not supposed to send our thanks on here but I think that's wrong: thank you for taking the time out to help!